# How to query data from specific primary shards in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

I want to query data only from primary shards (not replica shards) in elasticsearch.

I try using `preference` to query specific shards in elasticsearch. But how do I know which shards are primary shards to fill after `preference=_shards:` ?

```
GET my_index/_search?preference=_shards:0
{
  "_source": ["id", "handle"], 
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            ...
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you'd want to search only primary shards? What's your use case?

Comment: I want to get data from ES as fast as possible (after updating documents without the refresh flag). I think the delay from primary to replica can cause data to be wrong

Comment: How are you retrieving the data you've just indexed? By ID via a GET call or via a normal search?

Comment: I retrieve data via normal search, with filter, term,...

Comment: If you retrieve data via normal search and you state `without the refresh flag` then it's not gonna work as data is only searchable once refreshed, whether via the primary shards or not.

Comment: Ok I understand, but there is no way to just query from the primary shard in elasticsaerch, right? :((

Comment: I think you misunderstand how it works. Maybe explain your use case differently and why you think it's worth querying only the primary shards.